# How to remove trailing zeros from QGIS Graduated Style Class labels?

Tags: qgis, style, thematic-map

I'm sure I've seen a solution to this before but now I can't find it.

When using the graduated fill style in QGIS I get lots of trailing zeros in the labels. This makes my legends look messy in the print composer.

Is there a way to automatically remove these?

[image: Graduated fill style with trailing zeros]

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to auto change this at least in v2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the simplest method I've found so far:

1. Open layer properties
2. Save style as a QGIS Layer Style File
3. Open the resulting .qml style file in your favourite text editor
4. Use find and replace to identify trailing zeros and replace with a zero length string
5. Apply the altered layer style in QGIS

**Note:** Be careful when doing the find and replace as the lower & upper values may have a different number of trailing zeros to the label value. If you're not careful you can accidentally increase the values by factors of ten!

Comment: Note: This has all been sorted in QGIS 2.6

Comment: How has it been sorted? :S
Edit: I see the "precision" input field in categorized vector layers but not on pseudocolored raster layers, guess there's not an option for the later? :(