# What's the QGIS Legend Format Syntax to label percentage values?

Tags: qgis, legend, qgis-2.6

I asked a question about formatting legend text a while back and I'm happy to see the issue has been solved in QGIS 2.6:
[How to remove trailing zeros from QGIS Graduated Style Class labels?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/81324/8891)

But I'm having trouble tracking down a syntax guide for the new legend format options.

- Is there a guide available as I haven't managed to track one down (QGIS documentation search for 'legend format' returns no results)?
- Is it possible to enter decimal values and for this to be presented as a
  percentage (ie multiply by 100 and stick % on the end)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can multiply the value by 100 in the column definition and then add the % signs in the legend format as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Also works in QGIS 3

Comment: Also in QGIS 3 you can add the units of Measure, for example:
%1 - %2 $ per SQM