# What's the QGIS Legend Format Syntax to have thousands separated by commas?

Tags: qgis, style, legend

I have numbers in the millions and would like to know what string to enter in the `Legend Format` box to have thousands separated by commas ex: `2,000,000`

[image: QGIS example]

Comment: Any news on this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible (yet) for the *Legend Format* to include expressions such as those from the **Field Calculator**.

A workaround is to manually insert the commas into the correct places in the Legend (this can be laborious if you have a lot of items) and then click **Apply**.

**DO NOT CLICK "CLASSIFY" AS THIS WILL RESET YOUR LEGEND.**

[image: Graduated with commas]

Comment: Yeah, beyond doing things manually as you say doesn't look too promising.
Even the [percentage question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122966/whats-the-qgis-legend-format-syntax-to-label-percentage-values) had a similar solution

Comment: @raphael - Yes, you could always [open a feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) and hope they implement a viable solution in the next QGIS version :)

Answer (score 4):

For **QGIS3.X** I still don't know of a method to do this using the *Legend Format* but here's a PyQGIS script (can be run from the Python Console) to apply a thousands seperator to a given layer assuming it's using a *graduated* symbology:

```py
    for lyr in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        if lyr.name() == 'sales': #replace with your layer name
            renderer = lyr.renderer()
            if renderer.type() == 'graduatedSymbol':
                myRenderer = renderer.clone()
                idx = 0 
                for r in myRenderer.ranges():
                    lv = f'{int(r.lowerValue()):,}'
                    uv = f'{int(r.upperValue()):,}'
                    myRenderer.updateRangeLabel(idx,lv + " - " + uv)
                    idx+=1
                lyr.setRenderer(myRenderer)
                lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the very helpful answer by 15Step.
As a further modification - here is code that can be used to divide by 1000 and insert a 'k' at the end, e.g. for population figures.
This version works on the current layer. (Don't have to explicitly add layer name into the code, just select the layer then run the script).

As a check, it prints the layer name and the new scales to the console.

```
for lyr in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
if lyr == iface.activeLayer():
    print (lyr.name())
    renderer = lyr.renderer()
    if renderer.type() == 'graduatedSymbol':
        myRenderer = renderer.clone()
        idx = 0 
        for r in myRenderer.ranges():
            lv = f'{int(r.lowerValue()/1000):,}'
            uv = f'{int(r.upperValue()/1000):,}'
            tmp = lv + " - " + uv + "k"
            myRenderer.updateRangeLabel(idx,tmp)
            print (idx, tmp)
            idx+=1
        lyr.setRenderer(myRenderer)
        lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

Here is a sample after
[image: Sample Population Legend in 'k']

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421312/labeling-numerical-data-with-thousands-separator) shows how to alter your system settings in QGIS 3.x to show thousands commas. While this solves your problem, it does not solve it from the LEGEND menu.