# Is it possible to change number format to scientific in QGIS layer legend?

Tags: qgis, legend, format

I have a layer with really small values and the classes in the legend do not look nice both for work in QGIS but also in the print layout.

[image: QGIS layer properties window]

Is it possible to somehow change the format of the numbers in the layer legend so instead numbers like:

0.000012345

I could get scientific notation:

1.2345e-5

or do I have to manually convert the numbers from the legend somewhere "outside" - maybe in some online tool [like this](https://www.calculator.net/scientific-notation-calculator.html) and then paste it back in the legend as class label?

I googled and also looked in the QGIS documentation but did not find any solution.

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/145004/whats-the-qgis-legend-format-syntax-to-have-thousands-separated-by-commas generalised to "how do I control the format of legend numbers". The python code in one of the answers, modified, could work to return scientific notation. I was surprised that expressions can't be used in the format box and I'm not sure if that's a requested feature...

Comment: Using 3.16.1 I automatically get `1e-09` for e.g. `0.000000001`

Comment: Looks like a feature request from 7 years ago... https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/16552

Answer (score 1):

For now, I think it's not possible in the **layer properties**.

But you can do something with the legend item in your layout by **adding an expression to the vector layer and each child symbol's label** with an expression like this :

```
    array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
    --split with dash
    string_to_array( @symbol_label,'-'),
    to_real(
    --replace comma by point (useful for french like me)
    replace(@element,',','.'))),' - ')
```

### Documentation :

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_legend.html#data-define-the-legend-labels

### Example :

[image]