# QGIS: Layout Manager->Legend->Format numbers

Tags: qgis, labeling, layout-manager

In a layout, I have a legend with concentrations that are very low values with high precision. The preferred option is scientific notation. I employed the recommended expression in [Is it possible to change number format to scientific in QGIS layer legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385346), where
the code below is placed in the expression builder for the legend.

```
 array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
    --split with dash
    string_to_array( @symbol_label,'-'),
    to_real(
    --replace comma by point (useful for french like me)
    replace(@element,',','.'))),' - ')
```

It works, as shown in the image below for CH4; however, I would like more control over the precision. Another shortcoming of the solution is that it fails to render in scientific notation upon export to image or pdf.
The ideal solution is a way to format my legend numbers so that they render as such upon export and are ideally formatted to the same precision, ie '#.#E-##'. For example in Python,

```
>>scientific_notation = "{:.2e}".format(12300000)
>>print(scientific_notation)
>>1.23e+07
```

See the upper 3 values below for CO2 where I have hand changed the values.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new Expression Function by using your Python example.

In the Expression builder click on "Function Editor".
Now create a new function with the following code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def scientific_number(value,feature, parent):
    scientific_notation = "{:.2e}".format(value)
    return scientific_notation
```

Then you click on Save and Load Functions.

Now you can you can use the created funcion in the Expression builder (under Custom):

```
scientific_number(12300000)
>>1.23e+07
```

Details how you use the Function Editor:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#function-editor

Comment: That worked; however, to clarify to any others who may employ this method for legend conversion, I merged the 'sceintific_number' function above in the original code snippet I used. It controls the output precision and it rendered on export as scientific notation.   array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
    --split with dash
    string_to_array( @symbol_label,'-'),
    scientific_number( to_real(
    --replace comma by point (useful for french like me)
    replace(@element,',','.'))) ),' - ')