# Labeling numerical data with thousands separator

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I am running QGIS 3.18. I have successfully joined a .csv file to a shapefile and am now wanting to show some of the numerical data as labels on the map. Upon joining the .csv to the shapefile, the numerical data I want to show as labels does not show with a thousands separator (a comma, in this case).

So I'm attempting to use the field calculator to create (essentially) a duplicate numerical field, one that displays the thousands separator. I'm using the `format_number` expression to create this new field. In the Field Calculator window, the preview shows exactly what I'm hoping the output will look like:

[image]

However, when I click "OK" to run the calculator, the new field shows *without* the thousands separator:

[image]

I don't want to create a string variable, because I'd like to display the symbology in graduated colors (something you can't do with a string variable). What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want them for display purposes only, go to `Settings --> Options --> General` and check the box "`Show group (thousands) separator`":

[image]

You need to restart QGIS before changes will have effect.

For labelling purposes I suggest to use the expression `format_number()` directly in the `label with` or `value` field *(name depends on the QGIS version)* and not creating a column containing this as value:

[image]

*In case you really want this as data (I strongly advice to not do this), you need to format your field as string and convert the "number including thousands separators" to a string first. Because a "number" with thousands separator is not a number anymore and therefore cannot be stored in a numerical field. Be glad this is the case as it would lead you into a lot of trouble!*