# How to change decimal places when using graduated renderer?

Tags: qgis, style, decimal-points

The classifications given when I use the graduated renderer on QGIS under 'Layer Properties' are to 4 decimal places, and I would like none. I know I can use the rule based style and create my own classifications, but I have many of these to create.

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the "Precision" field to zero.

It's set to 4 by default.

[image: Precision]

Comment: I dont have the 'precision' field option, or 'Legend Format', is there a way of turning it on? maybe its the version I am using? I am on 2.4.0 Chugiak

Comment: According to [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/89704/51507), it was added in version 2.6